# -bash: sh: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I wanted to switch the shell to sh so I typed:

```
rakinar2@hotspot:~$ sh
```

But it says:

```
-bash: sh: command not found
```

How do I fix that?

Note: `test -e /bin/sh` returns 1!

EDIT:

`ls -l /bin/{,ba,da}sh` returns:

```
-rwx------ 1 rakinar2 rakinar2 563684 May  5 18:27 /bin/bash
```

`echo $PATH` returns:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin
```

And `sudo apt list --installed | grep "dash"` returns `0|1`

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Based on your `ls -l /bin/{,ba,da}sh` output your system looks thoroughly broken (or perhaps it is not Ubuntu?) - the `dash` shell is missing, and the `bash` shell has the wrong ownership (should be `root:root`) and permissions (should be `-rwxr-xr-x`)